# How to add caption data in videojs-caption plugin

Tags: jquery, video, video.js, caption, subtitle

I am using [videojs-caption Plugin](http://www.sampingchuang.com/videojs-caption) i have read documentation but i don't understand what should i give to data.

```
// initialize video.js
var player = videojs('video-id');

//load the caption plugin
player.caption({
   data: captionData
});
```

I have srt and vtt subtitles file on my server how can i give this file to data so it can load subtitles in player.

I am searching and working on it for about 8 hours ago i want to run this plugin so i can use this more functionality like forward subtitles and change styling of captions

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert the SRT or WebVTT file to this JSON format. It is a custom format for this plugin.

The creator does state it is similar to SAMI: https://github.com/spchuang/videojs-caption/blob/master/README.md so you could use that as a starting point.

Comment: How i can convert srt or webvtt file to json format ?